# How to map values reconstructed with a deep learning autoencoder back to categories

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, categorical-encoding, h2o

My colleague and I are working on a dataset full of categorical variables using an deep learning model with autoencoder of `H2O` package in `python2.7`.

As shown in the table below, we have used the autoencoder to reconstruct the data.  The problem is that we don't really know how to interpret the results since we don't know the mechanism behind the Deep Learning autoencoder which predicts the categorical variables.

Here is a sample of the original dataset with categorical variables:

[image: sample of the original dataset with categorical variables]

A sample of the reconstructed / predicted data follows:

[image: A sample of the predicted data]

We first want to understand how the model is treating categorical variables.  We also want to know how we can translate the reconstructed variables into the original categorical ones.

Comment: Need. More. Info. 1) What are you trying to predict (response), 2) What data do you have available (predictors), and 3) describe all of the above in terms of their distribution parameters. Oh, and 4) provide the hyperparameters of the model you are training and 5) provide some reasoning for using such a sophisticated model (multi-layer neural networks  and autoencoders aren't generally the first stop for a basic classification problem).

Comment: I don't think this should be on hold. @Josh none of this is needed to understand what the question, all she is asking is how to map reconstructed values in one-hot encoded variables back to the original categories. 1) it's unrelated to the type of response 2) she said that there were categorical predictors 3) not necessary 4) not necessary, all that matters is that it's H2O DL Autoencoder and 5) the goal here is not classification, it's reconstruction via DL Autoencoder.

Comment: @ErinLeDell good points all around, seems I didn't really understand the question and spoke too soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process by which categorical variables are encoded is detailed in the [H2O documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html).  There is a `categorical_encoding` variable in H2O algorithms and for Deep Learning the default is "One Hot Internal".  If you don't know what One-Hot encoding is, then you can read about it [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science) or look at my simple example below.  The "internal" designation just means that it's done on-the-fly, internally, in the algorithm, as opposed to first creating the whole, expanded one-hot encoded version of the whole dataset and then passed to the algorithm.  On-the-fly is more memory efficient, which is why it's done that way.

If you have a variable, `x`, with three categories, say "A", "B", "C", then the one-hot encoding of that looks like this:

Original data (e.g. 1 column data frame with header "x"):

```
"x"
A
B
B
C
NA
A
```

One-hot encoded version (a binary column for each category indicating which value, A, B, C or NA, corresponds to that row):

```
"x.A"  "x.B"  "x.C"  "x.missing(NA)"
  1      0      0          0 
  0      1      0          0 
  0      1      0          0 
  0      0      1          0 
  0      0      0          1 
  1      0      0          0
```

So if you use an autoencoder to reconstruct those values -- it's trying to predict the original values.  It probably rarely predicts the actual 0 or 1 value, but if you wanted to map these predictions back to original categories, then you'd look at the predicted values for each category, find which value is the highest, and then use that category.

For example, if row 1 in the dataset above was reconstructed like this:

```
"x.A"  "x.B"  "x.C"  "x.missing(NA)"
 0.8    0.1    0.001      0.1
```

Then you could assume that to be category "A". I don't think the values across the rows necessary add up to 1, but it shouldn't matter either way.  Just choose the label with the highest predicted value.

Comment: Such good news to be received in the morning, We were doing the same thing but we were not sure if it was correct. Thank you very much for taking time to replay to us in such fast & detailed manner.

Comment: @DaniahBanaa, if you found this answer helpful, then please consider
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.